# Dynamic MySQL querying to fill a GeoJson-data cache to be displayed in MapBox GL-JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I have a MySQL database with about 10,000 geographical points in it.

I also have a Mapbox GL-JS map running on a webpage that does a query to obtain the data, make it into a GeoJSON and then plot the points. Mapbox has no trouble with handling all the points.

However, querying all points is slow, so I have to limit the query to say 500 points. I figured out how to request only the points within the bounding box using MBRContains.

But now, every time I change the bounding box of my map by dragging or zooming, I have to request the entire bounding box, even though a part of the data may be already known. I am sure there must be a smarter way of doing this, by making some sort of a cache and only querying new data.

How should I make this? Requesting all data is costly so I can not do that and then process it into an R-tree. This is why I don't see yet how I could use this solution from Mapbox: [geojson vt](https://blog.mapbox.com/rendering-big-geodata-on-the-fly-with-geojson-vt-4e4d2a5dd1f2). However, I do know that all mapping applications and probably also RPG's need an algorithm for this.

So, how do I dynamically request and load my data?

Comment: You could try to add some kind of collection (Array) to keep track of what's added and what's removed. Thus, allowing you to cross-reference what you already have loaded and what you need to load as an extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dynamic vector tiles

Ideally, you want a mechanism to generate and serve vector tiles, which Mapbox-GL-JS can consume. Then, all the needs around fetching only the right data, caching etc are automatically met.

I can't recommend a specific tool, but it looks like TileStache's "[vector](http://tilestache.org/doc/TileStache.Vector.html)" provider can be connected to MySQL.

### Static vector tiles

If your data does not change very often (eg, hourly or daily), another approach would be to run a batch process like this:

```
1. Dump data to GeoJSON
2. Use Tippecanoe to generate .mbtiles file
3. Serve .mbtiles file using something like Tessera.
```

### Merge GeoJSONs

Using your existing stack, it would also seem not too complex to simply:

- Fetch initial dataset, store it as `points`
- When map moves, fetch new dataset, merge it into `points`
- Use `map.getSource().setData()` to display the merged dataset.

Not exactly a standard approach, but could work, if you can find a simple way to do the merge.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented it by keeping a buffer of 10 bounding boxes, and what data is within them. Every time I change my view, I check if I am in one of those bounding boxes. If so, nothing is done.
If not, the data from the new box is retrieved and added to the buffer (popping out the last one). A merge of all data is then plotted.
It's not the most efficient method, since I do not account for double-querying of overlapping boxes, but it works well.